# SQL Query to get data from another Excel - VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm developing a simple Excel VBA application to control a small stock in the company.
The idea is to have the packed boxes indexed by shelf.
In the Excel Database.xlsx file, we have two tables:
Pack: with the weight and dimensions of the packed boxes;
Trans: the shelf the pack was destined for.

Examples:

Pack:

```
| Pack_ID    | SalesIDLine    |
| --------   | --------       |
| 030F7D78   | SO00265293-1510|
| E2B9BD52   | SO00265293-130 |
```

Trans:

```
| Loc_ID  | Pack_ID   |
| ------  | --------  |
| D0305   | 030F7D78  |
| B0204   | E2B9BD52  |
```

But every time I run the query I get this error:
bof or eof is true of the current record has been deleted
BOF is false and EOF is true and the recordcount is -1

I tried this code:

```
Private Function SearchSalesID(SalesIDLine As String) As String()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim result() As String
    Dim index As Integer
    
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = DataBase_Path & "\" & DataBase_Name

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
              "Data Source=" & filePath & ";" & _
              "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Loc_ID FROM [Trans$] AS T INNER JOIN [Pack$] AS P ON T.Pack_ID = P.Pack_ID WHERE P.SalesIDLine LIKE '" & SalesIDLine & "%'"
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    result = rs.GetRows
    
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
    SearchSalesID = Application.Transpose(result)
    
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        conn.Close
    End If
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        rs.Close
    End If
    SearchSalesID = Array() 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your code is working - almost.

Problem is that `recordSet.GetRows` returns a 2-dimensional array - even if you get only one row and/or one columns. What seems a little bit counterintuitive is that the first index gets the column number, the second the row number, but that's probably the reason for your `Application.Transpose` statement.

However, no matter if you use transpose or not, the result is always 2-dimensional, and your function definition says it returns a 1-dimensional array. Therefore you get a type mismatch when you assign the result of `Transpose` as function result.

Depending on your needs, you need to manually create a 1-dimensional array, or change the return type of your query. Instead of the transpose, you could for example use this piece of code

```
ReDim resultVector(LBound(result, 2) To UBound(result, 2))
Dim row As Long
For row = LBound(result, 2) To UBound(result, 2)
    resultVector(row) = result(0, row)
Next
SearchSalesID = resultVector
```

Now there is one more thing you need to deal with: What happens if the query doesn't return any values? I used the following function in the past. I use *Early binding*, change the type of rs to `Object` if you don't want that.

```
Public Function GetDataFromRecordSet(rs As Recordset) As Variant
    If rs Is Nothing Then
      Exit Function
    ElseIf rs.State = 0 Then    ' State = 0: RS is closed
      Exit Function
    ElseIf rs.EOF Then
      Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim result
    On Error GoTo GetDataFromRecordSet_ERROR
    result = rs.Getrows
    GetDataFromRecordSet = result
    Exit Function
    
GetDataFromRecordSet_ERROR:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    
End Function
```

This function will return Empty as result if for any reason nothing could be read from a recordset object - in daily life that's mainly the case if there is no data in the query. You need to think about how you want to reflect this in your code. You could return `Empty` (in this case you need to change the return type of your function to `Variant`), or if you want to return an Array with one element that is "")...

Returning Empty:

```
Private Function SearchSalesID(SalesIDLine As String) As Variant
    (...)
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    result = GetDataFromRecordSet(rs)
    rs.Close

    If IsEmpty(result) Then Exit Function  
    (...)
End Function
```

Returning a dummy array:

```
Private Function SearchSalesID(SalesIDLine As String) As Variant
    (...)
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    result = GetDataFromRecordSet(rs)
    rs.Close
    
    If IsEmpty(result) Then
        ReDim resultVector(0 To 0) As String
    Else
        ReDim resultVector(LBound(result, 2) To UBound(result, 2))
        Dim row As Long
        For row = LBound(result, 2) To UBound(result, 2)
            resultVector(row) = result(0, row)
        Next
    End If
    SearchSalesID = resultVector
End Function
```

Comment: Work perfectly, only with small modifications:  "Dim rs As Variant" and "Dim result As Variant" and "Public Function GetDataFromRecordSet(rs As Variant) As Variant"

Comment: If you don't want to use Early binding, you should at least declare object variables as `Object`, not as `Variant`: `Dim rs As Object`. `Dim result` is lazy for `Dim result As Variant`, effectively it's the same.

Comment: I'll apply that. Thank you so Much!!!